# Behavior of complex exponential as imaginery coefficient tends to infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This has occurred in my undergraduate complex analysis textbook:

suppose $e^z=e^xe^{iy}$ ,  what happens when $y\Rightarrow\infty$

my intuition is that since $y$ denotes the phase of the circle with $R=e^x$, when $y\Rightarrow\infty$ the point is the entire circle, however if we interpret from, $e^z=e^x(cos(y)+isin(y))$ then $e^z$ oscillate as $y\Rightarrow\infty$

I don't think both of my interpretation is correct, can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two forms, and $e^{iy}=\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$ just rotates around the unit circle over and over again.  Thus $e^z$ just rotates around the circle with radius $e^x$ over and over again.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say, the radius is not constant, so you have a variable radius, which is not evident in the first interpretation, since your radius is now $e^xcosy$

Comment: @user1433153: The radius is constant.  $\cos^2y+\sin^2y=1$, and $\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$ is the point on the unit circle after traveling $y$ radians counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis.  Multiplying by $e^x$ just stretches it out to the circle with radius $e^x$.